# Multiplication of matrix by row vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

> Let $A, B$ be matrices such that the product $AB$ exists. How can we write $AB$ in terms of the rows of $B$?

Suppose the rows of $B$ are $r_1, ... , r_k$

My question is, when we do matrix multiplication,

$$A \begin{bmatrix} r_1 \\ \vdots \\ r_k \end{bmatrix}$$

where the $r_i$ are **row vectors** of $B$, how do I rewrite this?

Comment: You have to expand $A$ as well.

Comment: You may find this video lecture useful, particularly around the 12minute mark: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06-linear-algebra-spring-2010/video-lectures/lecture-3-multiplication-and-inverse-matrices/